# Azure: What is the use, and how could even work deploying multiple VMs to one single Cloud Service?

Tags: azure

I am a bit confused about the Azure Cloud Service, and what's its use. I mean what is the *concept*, at least in the use case if one would like to run only VMs and not interested in "Web Sites" (newly: "Wep Apps")

First I thought it is for reserving IP and domain name (I mean myservice.cloudapp.net). (Then I discovered it is not even capable to reserve a static fixed public IP between VM shutdowns/starts, unless you do PowerShell homework)

But the most confusing thing for me: it seems that is possible to deploy multiple Azure VMs to one single Cloud Service. However the Cloud Servie is what have public IP and domain name, then how it is possible to have multiple VMs on the same IP?

Comment: This should be posted to ServerFault, not StackOverflow. Also: Cloud Services are a legacy element of the "classic" API + deployment model.. VM's created with the new Azure Resource Manager API no longer employ this construct.

Comment: David thx for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual machines deployed into the same cloud service will have name resolution by default. This is possible because Azure provides a multi-tenant DNS server for your virtual machines. The Azure DNS server does not support the advanced records needed for workloads like
Active Directory. In those workloads, deploying your own DNS server is a requirement.

To access virtual machines inside of the cloud service externally, you create an endpoint. An endpoint can refer to a single virtual machine, or it can be configured as part of a load balanced set. To access an individual virtual machine, you create an endpoint with an unused public port that forwards traffic to the private port on the virtual machine itself.

Virtual machines are exposing port 3389 (Remote Desktop) to the outside world through separate endpoints. To access the virtual machines individually through the single IP address of the cloud service (the VIP), an unused public port must be used for each virtual machine endpoint (6510 and 6511 in this case) that is configured to forward to the internal port 3389 on each virtual machine.

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding, all VMs will be available on the same IP, so I have to map public ports to private to resolve the ambiguity. Is this also means it is not possible to have 2 separate VM, a web server on both, and both web server listen (publicly) on 80 -> one of the must be mapper out (publicly) to an other say 81. Both can listen on 80 on the private port.

Comment: Yes it is possible, you will need to configure an endpoint on each VM separately. More on endpoints - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/

Comment: David Makogon is right this should be posted on Server Vault. Please mark as answer if it is helped, if you need more details post on Server Vault